# Adding QueryTimeout parameter to command string

Tags: vb.net, db2, database-connection

I have a small web app that runs sql queries for users, that prints the results to pdf/csv. For larger queries, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR [57014] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.  SQLSTATE=57014

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception: ERROR [57014] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.  SQLSTATE=57014
```

After doing [research](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21450816), It turns out I need to add a `QueryTimeout` parameter to my connection string. I don't have much experience with vb.net aside from some simple edits. My relevant code looks like this:

```
Imports IBM.Data.DB2
Dim conn As New DB2Connection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(ddDatabase.SelectedValue))
Dim cmd As New DB2Command(strSQL, conn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem I think you should set the CommandTimeout on the DB2Command not the max time allowed to establish the connection

```
Imports IBM.Data.DB2
Dim conn As New DB2Connection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(ddDatabase.SelectedValue))
Dim cmd As New DB2Command(strSQL, conn)
cmd.CommandTimeout = 200
```

[DB2.CommandTimeout](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2CommandClassCommandTimeoutProperty.html)

> The time (in seconds) to wait for the command to execute. The default
>   is 30 seconds.